# Adicionar 0 depois da vírgula

Tags: python-2.7

Tenho uma *string* `str(owner.Vr_real).replace('.',',')` que recebe valores do tipo:

- 2045,5
- 3040,45
- 4042,05

Veja que o primeiro número não completa com 0 (ex: 2045,50). Qual função eu poderia utilizar para adicionar o 0 no final? Tentei utilizar `zfill`, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa dar uma olhada em [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Percebo que você deseja primeiramente trocar os pontos por virgula e depois definir a quantidade de casas decimais. Te indico a fazer o contrario. Primeiro defina a quantidade de casas decimais e depois transforme os pontos em virgula.

Você deveria usar:

```
str("%0.2f" % (owner.Vr_real)).replace('.',',')
```

Comment: Pois é, o primeiro exemplo da documentação já teria respondido minha questão:

>>> print '%(language)s has %(number)03d quote types.' % \
...       {"language": "Python", "number": 2}
Python has 002 quote types.